# React: search form with multiple inputs is submitting separate search each time additional input is used

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, methods, axios

My search form is dynmically created using a ajax call for the inputs. Each input can then be used alone or in combination with other inputs to narrow down the search results. The problem I am having is that the submit method is running a new search each time an additional input is added to the form. For example: User just searches with one input. Submit method runs once. User searches with two inputs. Search runs once for the single input and then another time for the two inputs. And so on...

Here is my parent file..

```
  class SearchPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);


      this.state = {
        labels: [],
        contracts: [],
        formValues:[],
        pdfs:[],
        titles:[],
        alertShow: false,
        show: false,

      };
      this.onClick = this.handleContract.bind(this);
      this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
      this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
      this.handleShowAlert = this.handleShowAlert.bind(this);
      this.handleCloseAlert = this.handleCloseAlert.bind(this)
    }

    initialState = { 
      formValues: {},
    }

    state = this.initialState

    componentDidMount(){
      this.loadLabels();
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
    }
    toggleHidden () {
      this.setState({
        isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
      })
    }

    handleFormReset = () => {
      this.setState(() => this.initialState)
      this.setState({contracts:[]})
    }

    handleClose() {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    handleShow() {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    }
    handleCloseAlert() {
      this.setState({ alertShow: false });
    }

    handleShowAlert() {
      this.setState({ alertShow: true });
    }
    loadLabels = () => {
      API.getLabels()
        .then(res => {
          const labels = res.data;
            this.setState({ labels })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

    handleInputChange = (key, value) => {
       const newFormValues = Object.assign({}, this.state.formValues, {[key]: value});
       this.setState({ formValues: newFormValues })
    };

    handleContract = (id) => {
      API.openRow(id)
      .then(res => {
        const pdfs = res.data;
        this.setState({pdfs});
        this.props.history.push({
          state: { labels:this.state.labels,
            pdfs:this.state.pdfs,
            titles:this.state.titles }
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
      API.titles(id)
      .then(res => {
        const titles = res.data;
        this.setState({titles});
      })
      this.setState({ show: true });
    }

    handleFormSubmit = event => {  
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = this.state.formValues
    let query = '';
    let keys = Object.keys(formData);
    keys.map(k => { 
      if (query !== "")
      query += `&`;
      query += `filter=`
      query += `${k}|${formData[k]}`

      return this.loadContracts(query);
     })
    };
    noResults() {
      this.setState({alertShow:true})
    }
    loadContracts = (query) => {
    API.search(query)
    .then(res => {
      const contracts = res.data;
      if (contracts.length > 0 ){
         this.setState({ contracts });
      }
      else {
       this.noResults();
        this.setState({contracts:[]});
      };
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

render() {

return ( 
<div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}>
  <div className="jumbotron">
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Contract Document Search</h1>
    </div>
<br/>
  <Container>


  <SearchForm 
    labels={this.state.labels}
    handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
    handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
    handleReset={this.handleReset}
    handleFormReset={this.handleFormReset}
    />

    <div className='modal'>
          <Modal show={this.state.alertShow} 
          onHide={this.handleCloseAlert}
          {...this.props}
          size="sm"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Body>No results found</Modal.Body>
          </Modal.Header>
        </Modal>
      </div>
</Container>
</div>

<div className="container">
 <div className="jumbotron-fluid">
 </div>
  <SearchResults 
    labels={this.state.labels}
    contracts={this.state.contracts} 
    pdfs={this.state.pdfs}
    handleContract={this.onClick}
    handleTitles={this.onClick}
    />
    <br/>
    <br/>

</div>
    );
  }
}
export default SearchPage;
```

And My search form component..

```
  export default class SearchForm extends Component {

    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);

      this.state = { 
      };
    }

    render() {
      return ( 
<form className="form-inline col-md-12" onReset={this.props.handleFormReset}>

{this.props.labels.map(label => (
  <div className="card border-0 mx-auto" style={styles} key={label.Id}>
       <ul className="list-inline ">
          <span>
            <li>
              <Labels  htmlFor={label.DisplayName} >{label.DisplayName}:</Labels>
            </li>
            <li >
              <Input  
                key={label.Id}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  this.props.handleInputChange(label.DataField, event.target.value)}}
                value={this.props.newFormValues}
                maxLength="999"
                style={{height:34}}
                name="value"
                type="search" 
                className={"form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"} 
                id={label.DataField}
              />
            </li> 
          </span>
      </ul>
  </div>
))}

  <div className=" col-sm-12">

  <Button
        style={{ float: "left", marginBottom: 10 }} 
        className="btn btn-success"
        type="submit"
        onClick={this.props.handleFormSubmit}
      >
        Search
      </Button>

      <Help />

      <Button
        style={{ float: "left", marginBottom: 10 }} 
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        type="reset"
        onClick={this.props.handleFormReset}
      >
        Reset
      </Button>


  </div>

  </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had my return statement inside the input mapping.

```
handleFormSubmit = event => {  
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = this.state.formValues
    let query = '';
    let keys = Object.keys(formData);
    keys.map(k => { 
      if (query !== "")
      query += `&`;
      query += `filter=`
      query += `${k}|${formData[k]}`

      **return this.loadContracts(query);**
     })
    };
```

Solved by moving the return statement outside the mapping.

```
handleFormSubmit = event => {  
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = this.state.formValues
    let query = '';
    let keys = Object.keys(formData);
    keys.map(k => { 
      if (query !== "")
      query += `&`;
      query += `filter=`
      query += `${k}|${formData[k]}`

     })
      **return this.loadContracts(query);**
    };
```